How long would it take to build a 954 piece set?
How long will it take to build the Fortnite battle bus, which is a 954 piece LEGO set?

Different people build at different speeds. I guess a set of that size will take anyone at least a couple of hours, but anything from that and up is a valid guess.

We had a very similar question a number of years ago. While this one does specify a particular set, I think the likely answer is still too dependent on the person, or people, doing the assembly to be able to satisfactorily answer the question.

As others before noted, this can't be estimated easily - what I'd like to add is that beside the builder's experience, the style also affects build time. Some might like to rush the process, while others might take care in aligning all pieces perfectly or admiring the partial assemblies and the building techniques. If you can tell us the actual use case (i.e. why do you need the estimate - "is it going to be ready by Christmas", "can I build it during one episode of that show", "is the recipient going to get more value from it than from a book", etc), we might be able to help more.
